# SQL Function and Anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-function

I'm taking a class about databases. I am very new to it, so excuse me if this is an obvious error, but I've been working on this problem for hours and not sure what else to do.

The code is suppose to create a function to that
A.) Outputs the average netwin for a year given by a parameter
   (given by the formula (SeasonW-Seasonl) + (PlayoffW - PlayoffL)
B.) Outputs all of the coaches that have a netwin over the average 
C.) Returns the number of coaches that fits this criteria.
D.)Have a anonymous block that calls this function, and outputs two different messages depending on the return on the function. 
Now I have sucessfully done parts A, C, and D. But for some reason my function will not be created when I insert part B.

```
create or replace function GOOD_COACHES(season IN INT)
return INT
IS
netwin INT;
CNT INT;
BEGIN
       --Calculated netwin
       select AVG((SEASON_WIN-SEASON_LOSS) + (PLAYOFF_WIN-PLAYOFF_LOSS)) into  netwin from COACHESSEASON where YEAR = season; 

       --Prints out A
       dbms_output.put_line('Average Netwin is: ' || netwin);

       --This Line messes up the function, I don't know why
       select T.FIRSTNAME, T.LASTNAME from COACHESSEASON T where ((T.SEASON_WIN-T.SEASON_LOSS) + (T.PLAYOFF_WIN-T.PLAYOFF_LOSS))>netwin and YEAR = season;

       --Calculates the number of teams that satisfy average
        select count(T.FIRSTNAME) into CNT from COACHESSEASON T where ((T.SEASON_WIN-T.SEASON_LOSS) + (T.PLAYOFF_WIN-T.PLAYOFF_LOSS))>netwin and YEAR = season;

return CNT;
END;
--End of the Function
--Start of the Anonymous Block
 DECLARE
      x int := GOOD_COACHES(1998);
 BEGIN
      if x = 0 then dbms_output.put_line('We didn''t find any good_coaches!');
      else dbms_output.put_line('The No. of good coaches is ' || x);
      end if;
END;
/
```

That third line in the function messes it up and doesn't allow it to be called. If I comment it out, it works properly.
When I take it out of the function and make it into a regular SQL statement, it works.

```
select T.FIRSTNAME, T.LASTNAME from COACHESSEASON T where ((T.SEASON_WIN-T.SEASON_LOSS) + (T.PLAYOFF_WIN-T.PLAYOFF_LOSS))>0 and YEAR = /*RandYear*/;
```

If anyone understands why the function can not be created with that line it in, I would appreciate the advice. I also do not know how I would print out the results of the selected row in the function.

Comment: Functions are not a part of SQL per se, but rather something that a particular database management system (DBMS) brings, and the various systems tend to do it in different ways, so you need to tell us what DBMS you are using.

Comment: sqlplus is not a DBMS but a program of Oracle. According to the syntax it is Oracle. If you want the function to print something, you need to use dbms_output. When you select FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME, select them to variables and put_line similar to netwin string

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the `T.FIRSTNAME`s and `T.LASTNAME`s into anything so the statement is not valid for inclusion in a PL/SQL block.

There are likely to be multiple "good coaches" so you can't put the values into a single variable and will have to use a cursor or a collection.

Using collections, if you create a table type to collect the first and last names into:

```
CREATE TYPE VARCHAR2s_Table AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
/
```

Then you can use this to collect the first and last names (and as a bonus the collection size will tell you how many good coaches there are and you can skip the last query):

```
create or replace function GOOD_COACHES(season IN INT)
return INT
IS
netwin INT;
CNT INT;
firstnames VARCHAR2s_Table;
lastnames  VARCHAR2s_Table;
BEGIN
  --Calculated netwin
  select AVG((SEASON_WIN-SEASON_LOSS) + (PLAYOFF_WIN-PLAYOFF_LOSS))
  into   netwin
  from   COACHESSEASON
  where  YEAR = season; 

  --Prints out A
  dbms_output.put_line('Average Netwin is: ' || netwin);

  --This Line messes up the function, I don't know why
  select T.FIRSTNAME, T.LASTNAME
  BULK COLLECT INTO firstnames, lastnames
  from   COACHESSEASON T
  where  ((T.SEASON_WIN-T.SEASON_LOSS) + (T.PLAYOFF_WIN-T.PLAYOFF_LOSS))>netwin
  and    YEAR = season;

  FOR i IN 1 .. firstnames.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( firstnames(i) || ' ' || lastnames(i) );
  END LOOP;

  return firstnames.COUNT;
END;
/
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf3fb/1/0)